# php - errors de fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql

Boas,

Criei este codigo para fazer FETCH de todos os dados através de um SEARCH.

Se eu escrever por exemplo "Olaaaaa", ele não da erro e mostra a pesquina, mas se eu der espaço e excrever por exemplo "Olaaa Souuuuu", ele mostra este erro.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\Superfacil_v1.2.8.9\inc\class_search.php on line 32
```

A linha 32 é basicamente esta

```
    $smtp_category_cc = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM public_ads WHERE $construct";
    $smtp_category_qry_cc = $con->query($smtp_category_cc);
    $total_request = $smtp_category_qry_cc->fetch_assoc();
```

codigo total é

```
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_GET['search']));
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_GET['category']));
$x = 0; 
$q = str_replace(array("\\",";"), "", $name);  // remove ALL backslashes & remove ALL ";" -> for sql security: no (simple) injection of commands
$q = trim($q);
$search_exploded = explode(" ", $q);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each ) { 

    $x++; 
    $construct = " "; 

    if($x == 1) { 
        $construct .= "ads_title LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0"; 
    } else {     
        $construct .= "AND ads_brand LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0"; 
    }
} 

/**************************/
$smtp_category_cc = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM public_ads WHERE $construct";
$smtp_category_qry_cc = $con->query($smtp_category_cc);
$total_request = $smtp_category_qry_cc->fetch_assoc();     

echo '<p class="shop-results">Encontrados <span class="badge">'. $total_request['total'] .'</span> <strong>An&uacute;ncios</strong>. </p>';      
/**************************/    


$get_search = "SELECT ads_id, client_id, category_id, ads_title, ads_brand, ads_content, ads_price, ads_views, ads_image_1, ads_image_2, ads_image_3, ads_date FROM public_ads WHERE $construct";
$get_search_qry = $con->query($get_search);


if($get_search_qry->num_rows > 0) {
```

Poderiame dizer o que é este erro?

==========================
ERRO 2:

```
erro:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND ads_brand LIKE '%dsadsa%' AND category_id = '31' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_' at line 1
```

Comment: faça isto no seu código `$smtp_category_qry_cc = $con->query($smtp_category_cc) or die('erro:' . $con->error);`

Comment: Provavelmente é por falta de espaços em branco quando você concatena as strings para montar a SQL. Basta verificar o valor de `$smtp_category_cc`.

Comment: errou foi este , vou por acima

Comment: E o valor da variável que citei?

Comment: Sim é o valor do erro da variavel que disse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta espaços no começo e fim da string, pois senão eles vão se juntando/concatenando e isso vai fazendo algo que era para ser como:

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo='bar' AND baz='bar' AND bar='bar'
```

virar:

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo='bar'ANDbaz='bar'ANDbar='bar'
```

e o `$construct = " ";` também tem que ficar fora do foreach

```
$construct = " "; 

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each ) { 

    $x++; 

    if($x == 1) { 
        $construct .= " ads_title LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0 "; 
    } else {     
        $construct .= " AND ads_brand LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0 "; 
    }
}
```

Fora que pode adicionar o `or die` para pegar o erro (pode usar `if` também):

```
$smtp_category_qry_cc = $con->query($smtp_category_cc) or die('erro:' . $con->error);
```

Outra maneira de resolver o loop do `foreach` para adicionar itens ao where seria um array, por exemplo:

```
$wherearr = array();

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each ) { 

    $x++; 

    if($x == 1) { 
        $wherearr[]= "ads_title LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0"; 
    } else {     
        $wherearr[]= "ads_brand LIKE '%$search_each%' AND category_id = '$category' AND ads_active = 1 AND ads_end = 0"; 
    }
}


$construct = implode(' AND ', $wherearr);//Junta a array separada por espaços em uma string
```

Comment: Já não da erros, mas existindo um record com "Levada House", e eu pondo Levada House ele nao encontra, apenas encontra como House ou Levada... isso é normal?

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de melhorar o codigo ?